# Experiencing Css3 animation issue

Tags: css, animation

So I'm using this code from this book HTML5 for masterminds by J.D. Gauchat

(I will copy everything as it is in the book)
My index.html looks like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>Web Design</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header id="mainbox">
         <span id="title"> Internet box 2.0</span>
      </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My stylesheet looks like this

```
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #mainbox {
            display: block;
            width: 500px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            animation: myanimation 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    }
    @keyframes myanimation {
    0% {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    }
    50% {
    background: #FF0000;
    }
    100% {
    background: #FFFFFF;
     }
    }

    #title{
    font: bold 36px verdana, sans-serif;
    }
```

I have also used the `@-webkit-keyframes` and the animation simply doesn't happen like it should according to the book's instructions in fact nothing happens.

I am using the latest version of google chrome and have had no issues with transitions or 3d transformations. Just animations.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works ok in Chrome:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#mainbox {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
    animation: myanimation 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none;
}
@keyframes myanimation {
0% {
background: #FFFFFF;
}
50% {
background: #FF0000;
}
100% {
background: #FFFFFF;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
0% {
background: #FFFFFF;
}
50% {
background: #FF0000;
}
100% {
background: #FFFFFF;
 }
}

#title{
font: bold 36px verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FkEs/)